# How to pack files to .dta format for Hidden & Dangerous 2?

Tags: modding, file-format

How can I pack files back into a DTA file from the game "Hidden & Dangerous 2"?

I want to change several sounds in the game in the file `Sounds.dta`.

I unpacked the files using [HD2unpacker](https://github.com/M3tox/HD2unpacker), but that program does not have a re-pack option. I can’t find how to pack my changed files into a new dta file. Is it even possible?

Comment: Here is some insight about how it was done for Mafia (https://progamercity.net/ghack-tut/4747-mafia-dta-files-format-reversing-encryption-packing-algorithm.html) which uses the same dta/ encryption/ decryption as HoD. The actual keys can be found too https://hd2.fandom.com/wiki/DTA.

Comment: It looks like HD2unpacker was actively maintained as recently as two years ago, and the creator M3tox was still working on HD2 tools as recently as October. Have you considered reaching out to them to inquire about how to re-pack your files? They may be able to add such a feature, or give you tips on how to add it yourself using the source code they've published.

Comment: Thank you guys for answers :) I will try to contact with M3tox. It's only one way to decide this